Showing an absolute value-related inequality
I've come across a problem that seemed trivial at first but it wasn't.
The problem is the following:

$x$ is a real number such that $|x-\frac{1}{2}|\le\frac{3}{2}$. Show that $\frac{1}{2}\le x \le 2$ ou $-1\le x\le2$.

My approach: since $|x-\frac{1}{2}\le \frac{3}{2}$ we can conclude two things:
$x-\frac{1}{2}\le\frac{3}{2}$ and $x-\frac{1}{2}\ge\frac{-3}{2}$. Hence $-1\le x\le 2$. But that's not what is asked in the problem, so I'm really confused. Any help is much appreciated.

Well $\tfrac12 \le x \le 2$ or $-1 \le x \le 2$ is the same as $-1 \le x \le 2$ since the first interval is contained in the second, so you are both right.

Another way of thinking about this is that the distance of $x$ from $\frac12$ is $\le \frac32$ which means $-1\le x\le 2$.

What you've written starting "Show that..." is confusing.

Break down into cases:
If $x-\frac12\ge 0$, then $\left|x-\frac12\right|=x-\frac12\le\frac32$, so $\frac12\le x\le 2$.
If $x-\frac12\le0$, then $\left|x-\frac12\right|=\frac12-x\le\frac32$. In this case $0\le 1+x$, so $-1\le x$. At the same time, $x-\frac12\le 0$, so $-1\le x\le \frac12$.

I see,Thank you so much man. Very appreciated

We may as well not break it into cases but square both sides instead. It is somewhat mechanical but also a completely foolproof approach.
